# How to cast a python list into a pointer of type void in C

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, cross-language

I'm trying to learn how to use ctypes in Python and I came across this example in the documentation

```
class Bar(Structure):
   _fields_ = [("count", c_int), ("values", POINTER(c_void_p))]

bar = Bar()
bar.values = (c_void_p * 3)(1, 2, 3)
bar.count = 3
for i in range(bar.count):
    print(bar.values[i])
```

This would print

```
1
2
3
```

What I actually want is to convert an actual python list such as `arr = [1,2,3]` into the compatible type of `bar.values` in the example above. Is there any way that I could achieve such thing?

Comment: `[1, 2, 3]` is not an array. It is a list

Comment: That code doesn't seem to be in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) at all, and it doesn't seem to be a sensible way to use ctypes. You're creating an array with `void *` elements and implicitly casting integers to `void *` and back.

Comment: The [closest thing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#type-conversions) in the actual docs uses `POINTER(c_int)`. I don't know why you changed it to `POINTER(c_void_p)`, but it's probably not doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, all you want is to have an assignment for `values` based on an variable instead of hard coded numbers.

Then this will work

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
bar = Bar()
bar.values = (c_void_p * len(arr))(*arr)
bar.count = len(arr)
```